# Entropy Of Mouse Movement

Tags: c#

i am trying to calculate the entropy of mouse movement. i am not a c# programmer but i'm trying to port c++ code into it, so i might have screwed some things up beyond the actual math (which i do not understand, thus i used online resources)

i create a sorted dictionary for each position (x and y):

```
        SortedDictionary<int, int> freqx = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
        SortedDictionary<int, int> freqy = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
```

in a while loop where im supposed to move my mouse, i use this to capture and store values. the key is set to each mouse position (either x or y) and the value is supposed to be the number of times that certain x or y value occured:

```
                if(freqx .ContainsKey(curr_x))
                {
                    freqx[curr_x] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    freqx.Add(curr_x, 1);
                }

                if (freqy.ContainsKey(curr_y))
                {
                    freqy[curr_y] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    freqy.Add(curr_y, 1);
                }
```

then at the end of the loop, i attempt to calculate the entropy for each one like this:

```
    double entropyx = 0.0;
    foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in freqx)
    {
        double currfreq = Convert.ToDouble(entry.value) / 1;
        entropyx += currfreq * Log2(currfreq);
    }
    entropyx *= 1;

    double entropyy = 0.0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in freqy)
    {
        double currfreq = Convert.ToDouble(entry.Value) / 1;
        entropyy += currfreq * Log2(currfreq);
    }
    entropyy *= 1;
```

the value i last got from x was 2 and from y was over 700

i suspect the algorithm i used was bad (or i c&pasted wrong)

so what's up with my code?

btw, log2 is:

```
    double Log2(double Nr)
    {
        return Math.Log(Nr) / Math.Log(2);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Trial code:

```
public void GetMouseEntropy()
        {
            RichTextBox1.Text += "Started..." + Environment.NewLine;

            SortedDictionary<int, int> freqx = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
            SortedDictionary<int, int> freqy = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();

            int curr_x = 0;
            int curr_y = 0;

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            while(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 2000)
            {
                curr_x = Cursor.Position.X;
                curr_y = Cursor.Position.Y;

                if (freqx.ContainsKey(curr_x))
                {
                    freqx[curr_x] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    freqx.Add(curr_x, 1);
                }

                if (freqy.ContainsKey(curr_y))
                {
                    freqy[curr_y] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    freqy.Add(curr_y, 1);
                }

                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            sw.Stop();

            double entropyx = 0.0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in freqx)
            {
                double currfreq = Convert.ToDouble(entry.Value) / 1;
                entropyx += currfreq * Log2(currfreq);
            }
            entropyx *= 1;

            double entropyy = 0.0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in freqy)
            {
                double currfreq = Convert.ToDouble(entry.Value) / 1;
                entropyy += currfreq * Log2(currfreq);
            }
            entropyy *= 1;

            RichTextBox1.Text += "X: " + entropyx + ", Y: " + entropyy;
        }
```

Comment: alright, done, bro. the values are even more screwed up now

Comment: How many samples did you collect in your while-loop?

Comment: I have collected a few thousand. I also tested multiple variations of the Shannon Entropy algorithm with just random numbers and {4, 4, 4, 45} returned a supposed entropy of over 200, so theres definitely something wrong im doing there. i am not sure at the "currfreq" part how im supposed to calculate it.

Comment: I tested with your code with random numbers and could not see any skew. `entropyx=2` means that you got only two colissions (same y value twice), all other y values were unique.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding how it works, is the value not supposed to be between 0 and 8?

Comment: I did see many different variations under the name of the "Shannon Entropy Formula". Not exactly sure which it is as the Wikipedia page is like an alien language to me, but I will use like you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the Shannon entropy is (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))):

H = - Sum(p(i) * log2(p(i)))

where p(i) is the probability that a certain outcome i occurs and the sum runs over all possible outcomes.

As your freq collections contain the number of occurrences, not the probabilities, you have to devide by the total number of samples when summing up.

Also, the "-" sign in the formula was missing.

```
double entropyx = 0.0;
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in freqx)
{
    double currfreq = Convert.ToDouble(entry.value) / sampleCount;
    entropyx += currfreq * Log2(currfreq);
}
entropyx *= -1;

double entropyy = 0.0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in freqy)
{
    double currfreq = Convert.ToDouble(entry.Value) / sampleCount;
    entropyy += currfreq * Log2(currfreq);
}
entropyy *= -1;
```

where `sampleCount` is the total number of samples collected.

You might want to extract the algorithm to a re-usable method like the following:

```
double ShannonEntropy(IReadOnlyCollection<int> frequencies)
{
    var samples = frequencies.Sum();

    double entropy = 0.0;
    foreach (var freq in frequencies)
    {
        if (freq > 0)
        {
            double prob = Convert.ToDouble(freq) / samples;
            entropy -= prob * Math.Log(prob) / Math.Log(2);
        }
    }
    return entropy;
}
```

which can than be called like `ShannonEntropy(freqx.Values)`.